# Specific options to nodejs ws.Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Can someone explain me what disableHixie, clientTracking in nodejs websocket library 'ws' means:

```
new ws.Server([options], [callback])

options Object
host String
port Number
server http.Server
verifyClient Function
path String
noServer Boolean
disableHixie Boolean
clientTracking Boolean
callback Function
```

I can't find a conclusive description what it means.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hixie-76 is an old and deprecated protocol supported by WebSocket, but this protocol is still in use in some versions of Safari and Opera. Default value in library 'ws' is **false**, but you can  disable the setting and set the **disableHixie** option to **true**.

The **clientTracking** option provides access to a collection of active WebSocket clients. Default value is **true**. See below:

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server:app });

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
   .....
   console.log('Total clients: ', wss.clients.length);
   ....
}
```

**Edit: additional information:**

The **verifyClient** function allows you to add any custom code to accept or reject incoming connections. Your code receives an `info` object with three members:

- `info.origin:` The origin of the connection
- `info.secure:` True if this connection is authorized or encrypted
- `info.req:` The `http.Server` request object for this connection

The `verifyClient` function can take one of the two forms:

```
var wss1 = new WebSocketServer ({ ..., 
   verifyClient: function(info) {
      # ...check data in info and return true or false...
   }
);

var wss2 = new WebSocketServer ({ ..., 
   verifyClient: function(info, callback){
      # ...check data in info and call
      # callback(true) for success or
      # callback(false) for failure 
   }
});
```

The first form is simpler if you can validate the client immediately.
For asynchronous validation, use the second form.